# Get hard drives SMART data with email notifications using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, smtp, hard-drive

if 
I want to use internal Windows resources to follow server disks health. So, I would like to schedule a PowerShell script on several servers. The script should take each server hard drives SMART status and send appropriate emails (through my internal SMTP server) to me. Some servers could contain more than one HDD.

My initial script is Ok and works fine:

```
$emailto="admin@example.com" 
$emailfrom="$env:COMPUTERNAME@example.com "
$emailserver="smtp.example.com "

$output = Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from Win32_diskdrive" | select Model, Status | out-string

function send-email
{
    $EmailSubj = "Disks SMART report on $env:COMPUTERNAME"
    $EmailBody = $output

    Send-MailMessage -To "$emailto" `
                         -From "$emailfrom" `
                         -Subject "$EmailSubj" `
                         -Body "$EmailBody" `
                         -smtpServer "$emailserver"
}

send-email
```

Typical output is something like this:

```
Model                  Status
-----                  ------
ST2000NC000            OK
ST2000NC000            OK
ST2000NC000            OK
ST2000NC000            OK
```

The question is how to avoid a lot of spam and email only if BAD statuses available? I would like to filter Get-WmiObject results in order to get the mails ONLY if at least one HDD status will not be "OK". I am not sure but there should be also "Degraded" and "Pred Fail" statuses. I tried different **foreach** and **If/Else** combinations, but I cannot find method how to force PowerShell check "OK" string from the Status property (and also for each HDD) to get my goal. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from Win32_diskdrive" | select Model, Status 
          | where-object {$_.Status -ne "OK"} | Out-String
```

Outputs drives if their status is not equal to "OK". This should account for any other status options, including "BAD".

Answer (score 2):

If you lose the `out-string`, you will have access to the object properties and will be able to filter on status not being OK.

But just a thought, I would rather have lots of emails as that way I would know the script is running or at least an email saying server 1 has no bad sectors etc...

```
$output = Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from Win32_diskdrive" | select Model, Status | where status -ne "OK"
```

Comment: Thank you, Simon! It is simple and good enough solution. I am dummy :) The only thing I should keep "Out-String" to get result in e-mail's body. And thank you for advice. I think I will use two Scheduled tasks - daily for full report and hourly for checking "Bad" only.